# Angular @ViewChild: keep whitespace when referring to innerHTML

Tags: angular, whitespace, innerhtml, line-breaks, viewchild

I use a templateRef and ViewChild() decorator to retrieve and display the innerHTML of an element. But all whitespace and linebreaks are gone when displaying it, it's just a long string.

Example:

in component.html:

```
<div>This is HTML</div>
<div [innerText]="code"></div>

<div>This is rendered HTML:</div>
<div #htmlRef>
  <div>
    <span>Hello world</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

in component.ts:

```
export class Component implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('htmlRef') htmlRef!: ElementRef;
  code!: string | null;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.code = this.htmlRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

In my template I get

```
This is HTML
<div _ngcontent-bkp-c29=""><span _ngcontent-bkp-c29="">Hello world</span></div>
```

instead of

```
This is HTML
<div _ngcontent-bkp-c29="">
    <span _ngcontent-bkp-c29="">Hello world</span>
</div>
```

(I don't mind the angular generated attributes _ngcontent)
I tried wrapping it in a `<pre></pre>` element, applying a class with `white-space: pre;`... made no difference.

How can I preserve the whitespace and linebreaks when displaying the innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on displaying it it's the nativeElement.innerHTML that strips it off.